# Getting 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map' while trying to fetch data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, classcastexception

I'm trying to fetch some data from `Firebase`, but getting this error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map` while trying to do so.

Here's what I'm trying;

```
    public void retrieveUserCounterAccepted() {
            databaseReferenceUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://appname-e1a13.firebaseio.com/users/");
            databaseReferenceUsers.child(uid).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    // error on the line below
                    newRequestAcceptedCounter = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    // error on line above
                    String requestAcceptedCounter = newRequestAcceptedCounter.get("requestsAccepted");
                    String requestsPostedCounter = newRequestAcceptedCounter.get("requestsPosted");
                    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
                    MenuItem requests_posted = menu.findItem(R.id.requests_posted_counter);
                    requests_posted.setTitle(requestsPostedCounter);

                    MenuItem requests_accepted = menu.findItem(R.id.requests_accepted_counter);
                    requests_accepted.setTitle(requestAcceptedCounter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    newRequestAcceptedCounter = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    String requestAcceptedCounter = newRequestAcceptedCounter.get("requestsAccepted");
                    String requestsPostedCounter = newRequestAcceptedCounter.get("requestsPosted");
                    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
                    MenuItem requests_posted = menu.findItem(R.id.requests_posted_counter);
                    requests_posted.setTitle(requestsPostedCounter);

                    MenuItem requests_accepted = menu.findItem(R.id.requests_accepted_counter);
                    requests_accepted.setTitle(requestAcceptedCounter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

What's going wrong here?

Please let me know.

Comment: dataSnapshot.getValue() is returning a string not a map. You are casting it as a map but clearly it is returning a string

Comment: @basic I have already mentioned that in the question.

Comment: I would assume that means that the return of `dataSnapshot.getValue()` is a `String` and you're trying to cast it as a `Map<String,String>`. Double check the data that you're putting into the database that it's being entered as a map.

Comment: @nukeform `dataSnapshot.getValue()`  returns `Object` and the data that is being entered in the map is `String`.

Comment: it is possibly to get old child data before change witghout ListenerforSingleValue?

Answer (score 0):

The specific class of the object returned by getValue() will be one of the supported JSON types:

- `Boolean`
- `String`
- `Long`
- `Double`
- `Map<String, Object>`
- `List<Object>`

The class is determined by the format (or other embedded type info) of the value stored in the database.

In your case, the value stored is a `String`.  It cannot be cast to a `Map`.

Use the Firebase Console to view the values stored as the children of `uid` to confirm they are what you expect. Perhaps you did not intend to store strings, but that it what is there.

**Update**

Instead of a `ChildEventListener` you need to use a `ValueEventListener`.  If am understanding your database structure correctly, a `uid` has children `requestsAccepted` and `requestsPosted`. Using a `ChildEventListener`, the callbacks will fire when either of those change and will return the simple string value of the changed child.  Your callback code is expecting the map of all the children of `uid`.  You can get this with a `ValueEventListener` on `uid`.

You could also continue to use a `ChildEventListener`, but on a reference that is one level up:

```
databaseReferenceUsers.addChildEventListener(...)
```

Comment: How can I retrieve the data then?

Comment: I have strings stored there and want to retrieve them

Comment: Your code is expecting each child to be a map of strings but that is not what you have stored.  Look at your code that stores the values for the children of `uid`.  What is the class of the objects you are storing?  Post the code.

Comment: `databaseReferenceUsers.child(MainActivity.uid).child("requestsPosted").setValue‌​(requestPostedCounterText);` here's how I'm saving the data on Firebase. The requestPostedCounterText is a string.